# Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, xcode8, firebase-cloud-messaging

I keep getting the error Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'. I have deleted my derived data folder, updated the pods, and reinstalled the pods multiple times. I am currently using xcode 8.2.1. My pod versions are 
Using Firebase (3.14.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.7.0)
Using FirebaseCore (3.5.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
Using FirebaseMessaging (1.2.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using Protobuf (3.2.0). I am using the newest version of cocoapods. Thank you for helping.

```
import UIKit
    import UserNotifications
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseInstanceID
    import FirebaseMessaging

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

        func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
            // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
            // [START register_for_notifications]
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            // [END register_for_notifications]
            FIRApp.configure()

            // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
            // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                   name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                                   object: nil)
            // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it doing the following steps on the command line:

1. pod repo update
2. Commented the pod 'Firebase' line from my Podfile
3. pod install (this removed the old Firebase)
4. Added the pod 'Firebase' line again.
5. pod install (added the new Firebase)